# How to make subpages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, directory

I've made a website with bootstrap and it's almost complete because I still need sub-pages for some pages, how do I make the page where posts from blog will appear? Do I have to make them all or a script can do that for me?

I tried to create a folder with the "main-page" name and then create the sub-page inside the folder, but it wont work...

Just to be clear:

This is what I've got: www.name.com/blog or /pricing etc...
This is what I want to make: www.name.com/blog/[somethingelse] (Sub-Page)

Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to create a folder inside the "blog" folder?

Then you can create the index.htm (or whatever the start page default is) so when you enter, using your example, www.name.com/blog/[newfoldername] the default page will load.

Hope that makes sense.

MSP

Comment: Got it, just created a new folder in the main directory called blog and then I've added and random name .html file, now i'm able to access it via www.name.com/blog/post-name.html, thanks!